# .htaccess not locating file

Tags: permissions, apache-2.4, .htaccess

I'm trying to move a client's site to a new server.

mod_rewrite is definitely enabled.

Test address is http://176.32.230.45/hubbwayhire.co.uk/ which loads fine.

http://176.32.230.45/hubbwayhire.co.uk/about.php also loads fine.

I have this in htaccess

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteRule ^about about.php
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f  
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
```

But loading the following: http://176.32.230.45/hubbwayhire.co.uk/about gives me the following:

```
Forbidden
You don't have permission to access /about.php on this server.
```

Permissions are also completely fine.

Server owners will not help us at all. Any help appreciated?

Comment: With the URL you're using the `RewriteBase /` is incorrect. That should `RewriteBase /hubbwayhire.co.uk/` or can be omitted I think.

Comment: You get the same error when you try to access `http://176.32.230.45/about.php` - which is what your code is doing (with the `RewriteBase` that HBruijn mentions above). The `RewriteBase` directive can be omitted if this `.htaccess` is in the `/hubbwayhire.co.uk` subdirectory. Also, your .htaccess would seem to be incomplete.

Comment: Also you have two `RewriteCond` directives with no `RewriteRule` after, so they do nothing, unless you missed a `RewriteRule`. When you get a 403, look in the error log and add what is in there to your question that relates to the 403.

Comment: @HBruijn Thank you so much the RewriteBase fixed it. Can't believe I've spent this much time on it and couldn't figure this out. I tried to remove the rewritebase but it didn't work either.